# other component not showing after I show the scrolltext

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

i am doing a project to calculate the charges for different weight of the parcel. however, the position of the component(label, button, textbox and scrolltext) did not place it in the manner i want.
i want the length label to be in the center top, and the length textbox next to it. similar to width label and height label.
the following is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st

class Delivery(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Delivery Charges Calculator(Ong Jia Sheng)")
        self.master.geometry("700x350") #width by height dimension

        #create the components
        #create RadioButtons
        self._salute = StringVar() #common variable for Radio buttons
        self._rb1 = Radiobutton(self,text="cm",variable=self._salute,value="cm")
        self._rb2 = Radiobutton(self,text="inch",variable=self._salute,value="inch")
        self._salute.set("cm") #value of radiobutton, this is to set default selection
        #create other components

        self._lenLb = Label(self, text="Length:")
        self._widLb = Label(self, text="Width:")
        self._heiLb = Label(self, text="Height:")
        self._weiLb = Label(self, text="Weight(kg):")

        self._lenTb = Entry(self, width=25)
        self._widTb = Entry(self, width=25)
        self._heiTb = Entry(self, width=25)
        self._weiTb = Entry(self, width=25)

        self._charButt = Button(self, width=15, text="Calculate Charge",command=self.calcCharges)
        self._cleButt = Button(self, width=15,text="Clear",command=self.Clear)

        self._stxt = st.ScrolledText(self,width=700,height=5)

        #place onto the window use grid layout
        self._lenLb.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self._lenTb.grid(row=0,column=5)
        self._widLb.grid(row=1,column=4)
        self._widTb.grid(row=1,column=5)
        self._heiLb.grid(row=2,column=4)
        self._heiTb.grid(row=2,column=5)
        self._rb1.grid(row=5,column=6)
        self._rb2.grid(row=5,column=7)
        self._weiLb.grid(row=8,column=4) 
        self._weiTb.grid(row=8,column=5)

        self._charButt.grid(row=9,column=5)
        self._cleButt.grid(row=9,column=6)

        self._stxt.grid(row=9,column=0)
        self.grid()

    def calcCharges(self):
        self._salute.set("inch")
    def Clear(self):
        self._salute.set("cm")

def main():
    app = Delivery()
    app.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The width of ScrolledText constructor is expressed in characters (not in pixels).

Since it is very wide (700 char) and alone in the  first column, other widgets are moved far to the right and outside the screen.